# How to construct a binary tree from Leetcode values list?

Tags: algorithm

For the following problem:

[image]

The output/correct result is specified as:

```
 Output: [3,9,20,null,null,15,7]
```

I'm not sure what that output actually represents. I tried to scan it by level . E.g 3 is the root, then its children are 9 and 20 (which does not work). So then what is the actual tree?

Comment: It looks like a BFS - first level is `3`, second - `9` and `20`, the last -  `null`, `null` (children of `9`), `15` and `7`.

Comment: LeetCode normally does this conversion for you. In your solution could you should really return an object-oriented instance of the tree, using the Node class or whatever the comment block before the template code suggests (it depends on the programming language). The LeetCode testing suite will silently convert your structured return value to this array format. It is not something you are supposed to take care of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's how the binary tree is represented.

Output is a list of nodes where for node `i` (starting from index 0), node `2*i+1` is its left child and node `2*i+2` is its right child. So if those nodes do not exist, the corresponding value in the list is represented as `NULL`.

In this case, node 0 has a value of 3, and its left child is shown in node 1 (`Output[1]`) with value 9, while its right child is shown in node 2 (`Output[2]`) with value 20.

However, node 2 (`Output[2]` with value 20) does not have any children so the values corresponding to its children (`Output[3]`, `Output[4]`) are shown as `Null`.

Comment: What you mention is how I was reading it but thought that were not correct.  So this is not a _sorted_ binary tree?

Comment: That seems to be what they mean. Binary trees aren't necessarily sorted.